# Open URL in webview and parse it show the image

Tags: android, json, android-intent, webview

I want to open a webview by clicking on a url. Url provides json data. How can I parse this data in the webview activity and show the image?

my url is: http://a.nextput.com/api/single-offer/23/89533a6f4248873b08ce52ce680f29e7/a/fs

and after clicking it my json comes on the webview is:

```
 {  
  "success":true,
  "offer":{  
  "packageName":"com.myntra.android",
  "campKey":"284",
  "app_name":" Myntra",
  "image_url":"https:\/\/media.go2speed.org\/brand\/files\/wadogo\/142\/thumbnails_100\/unnamed-3.png",
  "desc1":"No Incent\r\nNo Free-Recharge apps traffic\r\nNO SMS\r\nNo Email\r\nNo Adult traffic\r\nNo Bot Traffic\r\nKPI - purchase% >10% of Total Installs. If not met, CPI payout will be pro-rata.\r\nNote: No social media traffic allowed. No traffic from Datalead.\r\n\r\nThe caps provided are network wide. \r\nPlease ask AM for individual Caps by Mail and Skype.\r\nexpiry date: TBA\r\nThe offer will stop converting once we hit the daily\/monthly cap\r\nCPI per install\r\nOnly use the creatives provided by us.\r\n\r\nPayout Slab:\r\n0-10 INR - Nill\r\n10-50 INR - $0.40\r\n50-100 INR - $0.62\r\n100-125 INR - $0.70\r\n125+ - $0.90",
  "desc2":null,
  "rdata":"[]",
  "cats":"0",
  "banner_url":"http:\/\/thegraphicsfairy.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/03\/Free-Banner-Frame-Image-2-GraphicsFairy.jpg",
  "click_url":"http:\/\/www.google.com",
  "country":"IN",
  "payout":0.12
  }
 }
```

I have to just load the banner_url in my webview. Please help me to solve it.

Comment: You want to parse the json that this url returns, right? and what do you want to show in the image? and where do you want to show that image?

Comment: @Yashasvi Yes, I want to parse the json that this url returs. In the json, there is a banner_url which is a image, I just want to open this banner_url image in my webview. please help

Comment: Understood. Answered.

Comment: Simplest Method Get json data using Http GET request (Library like retrofit or native) and parse json and get the url of image and pass it to the image view using Picasso. if you need code then I can provide you.

Comment: @RameshKumar Yes please, provide the code. I'm totally confused how to do it.

Comment: this url is not giving above data, it is only giving status true. can you make this url returning proper data? as I can check it?

Comment: @RameshKumar I checked twice. It is giving the same json.

Comment: @RameshKumar If there is problem in the url please provide the code with steps. As above the json I'm getting from url.

Comment: I have answered the question you can check it.

Comment: @himanshu.tiwari :  You should accept the answer that solved your problem, so that it makes it easy for the coming users to find solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this:

1) get json from this url

2) parse that json and get banner_url from it

3) show that image in the webview.

In that case, first fetch json from the url using HttpURLConnection. Write a function similar to this :

```
public static String getJSON(String url) {
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        URL u = new URL(url);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        br.close();
        return sb.toString();

    } catch (ConnectException ex) {
        return ex.toString();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return ex.toString();
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                //disconnect error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After that, parse that json, and then do

```
webView.loadUrl(banner_url);
```

Don't load the initial url in the webview. That's used to just fetch json.

Comment: I have to do all this in a single activity which is my webview activity?

Comment: It depends on you. You can fetch and parse the json in the activity which calls webview activity and then pass only the banner_url to the webview activity. OR. you can do this all in the webview activity. Whatever suits you.

Comment: @himanshu.tiwari :  no problem. You should accept the answer so that coming users on this page know what to do :)

Answer (score 1):

Just parse like this

```
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject objOffer=obj.getJSONObject("offer");
String bannerUrl=objOffer.getString("banner_url");
```

You get the Banner Url here. 
Now just Load it in Webview.

```
WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
wv.loadUrl(bannerUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment I am sending you the code: I have used Retrofit Library for getting data and parsing:

In build.gradle

```
  compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
```

RetrotitActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.RequestInterceptor;
import retrofit.RestAdapter;
import retrofit.RetrofitError;
import retrofit.client.Response;
import retrofit.http.GET;
import retrofit.http.Path;

public class RetrofitAcitity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView ivBanner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_retrofit_acitity);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ivBanner = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
        callAPI(new String[]{"http://a.nextput.com/api/single-offer/23/", "89533a6f4248873b08ce52ce680f29e7/a/fs"});
    }


    public void callAPI(String[] url) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
        RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            }
        };
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(url[0])
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
                .build();
        final GetAPI git = restAdapter.create(GetAPI.class);
        git.getData(url[1], new Callback<ResponseJson>() {
            @Override
            public void success(ResponseJson gitmodel, Response response) {

                if (gitmodel != null) {
                    if (gitmodel.getSuccess()) {
                        if (gitmodel.getOffer() != null) {
                            if (gitmodel.getOffer().getBannerUrl() != null) {
                                Picasso.with(RetrofitAcitity.this).load(gitmodel.getOffer().getBannerUrl()).into(ivBanner);
                            } else
                                Toast.makeText(RetrofitAcitity.this, "NO image Banner", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Log.v("error", error.getKind().name());


            }
        });
    }


    public interface GetAPI {
        @GET("/{path}")
        public void getData(@Path(value = "path", encode = false) String path, Callback<ResponseJson> response);
    }

}
```

activity_retrofit_acitity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.ramesh.expandablelistview.RetrofitAcitity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!--<include layout="@layout/content_retrofit_acitity" />-->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/wallet_highlighted_text_holo_dark" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

ResponseJson.java

```
package com.ramesh.expandablelistview;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

/**
 * Created by Ramesh Kumar on 2/18/2016.
 */
//Generated From: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
public class ResponseJson {

    @SerializedName("success")
    @Expose
    private Boolean success;
    @SerializedName("offer")
    @Expose
    private Offers offer;

    /**
     * @return The success
     */
    public Boolean getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    /**
     * @param success The success
     */
    public void setSuccess(Boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    /**
     * @return The offer
     */
    public Offers getOffer() {
        return offer;
    }

    /**
     * @param offer The offer
     */
    public void setOffer(Offers offer) {
        this.offer = offer;
    }

}
```

Offers.java

```
package com.ramesh.expandablelistview;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

/**
 * Created by Ramesh Kumar on 2/18/2016.
 */

//Generated From: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
public class Offers {

    @SerializedName("packageName")
    @Expose
    private String packageName;
    @SerializedName("campKey")
    @Expose
    private String campKey;
    @SerializedName("app_name")
    @Expose
    private String appName;
    @SerializedName("image_url")
    @Expose
    private String imageUrl;
    @SerializedName("desc1")
    @Expose
    private String desc1;
    @SerializedName("desc2")
    @Expose
    private Object desc2;
    @SerializedName("rdata")
    @Expose
    private String rdata;
    @SerializedName("cats")
    @Expose
    private String cats;
    @SerializedName("banner_url")
    @Expose
    private String bannerUrl;
    @SerializedName("click_url")
    @Expose
    private String clickUrl;
    @SerializedName("country")
    @Expose
    private String country;
    @SerializedName("payout")
    @Expose
    private Double payout;

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The packageName
     */
    public String getPackageName() {
        return packageName;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param packageName
     * The packageName
     */
    public void setPackageName(String packageName) {
        this.packageName = packageName;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The campKey
     */
    public String getCampKey() {
        return campKey;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param campKey
     * The campKey
     */
    public void setCampKey(String campKey) {
        this.campKey = campKey;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The appName
     */
    public String getAppName() {
        return appName;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param appName
     * The app_name
     */
    public void setAppName(String appName) {
        this.appName = appName;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The imageUrl
     */
    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param imageUrl
     * The image_url
     */
    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The desc1
     */
    public String getDesc1() {
        return desc1;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param desc1
     * The desc1
     */
    public void setDesc1(String desc1) {
        this.desc1 = desc1;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The desc2
     */
    public Object getDesc2() {
        return desc2;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param desc2
     * The desc2
     */
    public void setDesc2(Object desc2) {
        this.desc2 = desc2;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The rdata
     */
    public String getRdata() {
        return rdata;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param rdata
     * The rdata
     */
    public void setRdata(String rdata) {
        this.rdata = rdata;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The cats
     */
    public String getCats() {
        return cats;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param cats
     * The cats
     */
    public void setCats(String cats) {
        this.cats = cats;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The bannerUrl
     */
    public String getBannerUrl() {
        return bannerUrl;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param bannerUrl
     * The banner_url
     */
    public void setBannerUrl(String bannerUrl) {
        this.bannerUrl = bannerUrl;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The clickUrl
     */
    public String getClickUrl() {
        return clickUrl;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param clickUrl
     * The click_url
     */
    public void setClickUrl(String clickUrl) {
        this.clickUrl = clickUrl;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The country
     */
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param country
     * The country
     */
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The payout
     */
    public Double getPayout() {
        return payout;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param payout
     * The payout
     */
    public void setPayout(Double payout) {
        this.payout = payout;
    }

}
```

I have created activity and call the service using retrofit and made the Class of model GSon will parse it and I will get the image.
If it helps then accept it. and feel free to ask if you can not understand.